# How to fail AzureDevops pipeline when test files are not found

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, dotnetcorecli

I have the following DotNet Test task in my pipeline

```
          displayName: 'unit tests'
          inputs:
              command: test
              projects: '**/*Unit*.csproj'
              publishTestResults: true
              arguments: '/p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:CoverletOutput=results/'
```

How can I fail the pipeline if no files matched the project pattern:  `'**/*Unit*.csproj'`?
Currently, it displays the current error message and moves on to the next task

`##[warning]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.`

Answer (score 3):

One could also run a bash script checking for the existence of the test result file (and that number of results is greater than 0):

```
- bash: |
    if [ $(test_results_host_folder)**/*.trx ] && [ $(grep -E "<UnitTestResult" $(test_results_host_folder)**/*.trx -c) -gt 0 ]; then
      echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=TESTRESULTFOUND]true"
    fi
  displayName: Check if test results file & results >= 1
- script: |
      echo No test result found
      exit 1
  displayName: No test result found
  condition: ne(variables.TESTRESULTFOUND, 'true')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Visual Studio Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops#arguments) task. It has a `minimumExpectedTests` parameter, so if you set it to 1, the task will fail if 0 tests are run.

Comment: It is worth noting that the VSTest task isn't cross platform so it won't work on a linux build agent.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we cannot set the task itself to make the pipeline fail when it cannot find the file.

For a workaround:

You could use the **Build Quality Checks task**  from [Build Quality Checks extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mspremier.BuildQualityChecks).

This task can scan all set tasks and check warnings. If the number of warnings is greater than the set upper limit, the pipeline will fail.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you have stages in your yaml pipeline, then you can do something like this, this will not run the next stage if the previous stage has failed

```
stages:
- stage: unittests
  displayName: 'unit tests'

- stage: nextstage
  dependsOn: unittests
  displayName: 'unit tests'
```

Comment: Welcome SO Zeeshan Abbas ! Thank you for your answer but this solution only works if the tests fail on the previous stage. At the moment the task succeeds even if no test files are found

Comment: Thanks @RedRose - not sure if the below could be of any use to you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807281/setup-of-azure-pipelines-yml-no-web-project-was-found-in-the-repository-with-a
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790735/no-package-found-with-specified-pattern-d-a-r1-a-zip